# Is this Young Justice character supposed to be Black Spider?

Tags: dc, character-identification, young-justice

Young Justice features a villain who appears nearly identical to Spider-Man. He wears a similar suit - albeit purple, sticks to walls, and fires red webbing from wrist-mounted bracelets. A quick Google search shows that on Wikipedia he's identified as Black Spider. From what I know of Black Spider, however, he's never stuck to walls or used red webbing - he's just a non-powered vigilante with above-average agility.

**Can someone confirm - using a non-Wiki source - that this character is Black Spider?** He seems to be a rather blatant rip-off of a Marvel character, right down to the same logo & skillset.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Black Spider [did](http://www.s8.org/gargoyles/askgreg/search.php?qid=15170) [appear](http://www.s8.org/gargoyles/askgreg/search.php?qid=14145) on the show, according to producer Greg Weisman, but I am unable to find explicit proof that the character you screenshot is meant to be him. However, his costume is quite similar to that of Eric Needham, the Black Spider that Weisman states is in *Young Justice*, so the answer seems to be yes.

[image]

As far as I can tell, his webbing was created for the cartoon.

Answer (score 1):

Greg had just come from working on "Spectacular Spider-Man" and brought Josh Keaton (the voice of the titular character) with him. Because they could and did have Spider-Man voicing Black Spider, they decided to switch up his powers and abilities to be more like an evil clone of the OG marvel character.

Personally it's my favorite version of the character but IDK I find Evil Spider-Man fun.

Comment: Could you, please, provide the source for this answer?

Answer (score 0):

In his second apparition, where he has a voice actor (in his first one he has no lines), check the credits and you'll see his name listed as Black Spider.

Comment: Hi there! For those of us who don't have access to the show, it would be better if you could [edit] a screenshot of said credits, or a Youtube clip or something; this would make for a better answer :)

Comment: Josh Keaton: https://www.imdb.com/title/tt2087632/?ref_=nm_flmg_act_3